# Android Get Keys from preferences.xml

Tags: java, android, preferences

I have a `PreferencesActivity` that shows a `preferences.xml` with checkboxes.

`preferences.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Keywords">
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="Essen" 
                        android:title="Essen" 
                        android:selectable="true" 
                        android:enabled="true"
                        android:persistent="false">
    </CheckBoxPreference>
    <CheckBoxPreference android:key="Kleidung" 
                        android:title="Kleidung" 
                        android:selectable="true" 
                        android:enabled="true"
                        android:persistent="false">
    </CheckBoxPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

PreferencesActivity:

```
public class PreferencesViewController extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

Now in a different `ListActivity` I want to show all Keys/Titles from the checked checkboxes.

I try to access the Preferences with

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

or

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("mypackage_preferences", 0);
```

But both dont really work.

When I call `prefs.getAll().size()` the result is 0.

I can access the Keys/Title with `getPreferenceScreen().getPreference(i).…` but it doesn't work from a different `Activity`, only from the `PreferenceActivity`.

Does anybody have a solution how to get this work?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a `PreferenceActivity` to accomplish this.

To access the preferences, that are used in your PreferenceActivity, you should use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

If your list of data comes from the server, than you can use a ListActivity / ExpandableListActivity / any custom activity to visualize it, but this way you need to write the handlers that change the preferences.

The common way to do this would be:

```
private void saveStringPreference(final String key, final String value)
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

If you need, you should create similar wrappers to deal with int, boolean, etc. values.

Comment: Thank you. I have been searching for this answer for about an hour.
I had a preferences.xml and preferences.java but I wanted to use another screen to set the values. Thanks again.

Comment: Why `getBaseContext()`?

Comment: I guess we'll never know

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = 
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

And then I can access the preferences via `prefs.get...()`, e.g. `prefs.getString(key)`.
Have you tried this?

**Edit:** Just checked - `prefs.getAll()` works as expected and returns a `Map` with all preferences.

Comment: The Problem is that I want to update these preferences from Internet/Server. So i dont know the keys for every checkbox. So the Preferences should be shown in an Activity/View, the User can check/uncheck them. I have to read the checked preferences and the preferences should be updated by a server… maybe the PreferenceActivity is not the right solution?! :-/

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. This is a classic RTFM, sadly. You should put the line below in your MainActivity's onCreate() method:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
```

This info can be found in the paragraph "Setting Default Values" of http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
SharedPreferences prefs = referenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

The preferences may be empty if you have never set them via the PreferencesActivity. Also I think your ListActivity has to be in the same package as the PreferencesActivity.